# Development Version of Exchange Server?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am looking to develop some custom code for Exchange. I would like to set up a "development" instance of Exchange. I looked at the Azure VM images to see if I can create one there that hosts Exchange, but no luck.

Is there a development version of Exchange available for writing prototypes, etc.?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure and an MSDN license to create a Dev environment for building your application(s).  Exchange and other enterprise MSFT apps are available if you have MSDN.

You'll need to purchase an MSDN subscription but that and depending on what version you choose will get you access to all of the products you'll need.  MSDN also includes up to $150 in monthly Azure credits, resetting each month for the duration of the MSDN license.  I run the MSDN "Test" subscription and get $100 a month for Azure.

https://www.visualstudio.com/products/subscriber-benefits-vs